# Force QMediaPlayer to update position accurately for video scrubbing application?

Tags: c++, qt, qtmultimedia, qmediaplayer

I am writing an application which will allow the user to scrub through an open video. Developing on Windows 7/8 with Qt 5.3, I have been using `QMediaPlayer` and `QVideoWidget` following the `qvideowidget` example project. The result has been pretty good, except that the `QVideoWidget` seems only to update during idle time. Still, it's a good start and it's usable.

However, when I build on Mac OS 10.10 (again with Qt 5.3), scrubbing behaves as though there were only one frame per second in the video. As I drag the "position" slider, the video jumps from one frame to the frame one second later, then one second after that, even though I am calling `QMediaPlayer::setPosition` several times with positions between those two frames.

The problem can be reproduced using the `videowidget` example that ships with Qt 5.3 here: `Qt\Examples\Qt-5.3\multimediawidgets\videowidget`. When the slider is dragged on a Windows machine, the `QVideoWidget` moves between frames that are spaced fairly close together. When the slider is dragged on a Mac (at least on mine), the `QVideoWidget` jumps between frames spaced about one second apart. No matter how long I wait for an "in between" frame to render, it won't happen unless I hit the "play" button.

I've tried calling `QMediaPlayer::play()` and `QMediaPlayer::pause()` one after the other to force an update, but this doesn't seem to work--`QMediaPlayer` works asynchronously, so the update doesn't have time to take effect.

If I check the value of `QMediaPlayer::position`, I find that it actually doesn't change between these jumps. It appears that when I call `QMediaPlayer::setPosition`, it is actually rounding the position to one second increments on a Mac and finer increments on a Windows machine.

Ideally, I would like to jump to a particular position in the video and render that frame immediately on the `QVideoWidget`. Is there any way to force `QMediaPlayer` to set the position accurately and update the associated `QVideoWidget`? Is there a better way to implement smooth scrubbing in a video?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: A bit more information: The “granularity” of the position stored in ```QMediaPlayer``` seems to be related to the length of the video, but only on the Mac. On a PC, even with a 2 GB video I can still seek to frames that are only 0.1 seconds apart. On the Mac, however, when I open a 2 GB video the granularity is about 3 seconds, but with a 400 MB video the granularity is about 1 second.

Does this ring a bell for anyone? I’m at a bit of a loss as to what’s going on here, so any help at all would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else has a similar problem...

My best guess is that the issue stems from limitations in the codec used by `QMediaPlayer`, since this seems to be the main difference between the two platforms. Rather than deal with the codec issues directly, I looked around for other options.

`MLT` (http://www.mltframework.org/) seemed promising, but it is a major pain to compile and the primary author seems to have settled on offering SDK support to commercial users only.

`libVLC` (https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC/) looks a lot better. In particular, I’ve been using `vlc-qt` (https://github.com/ntadej/vlc-qt). The latter has an interface that will look quite familiar to users of `QMediaPlayer` and `QVideoWidget`. It was an easy replacement in my own application, and the result was much smoother video scrubbing on both Windows and Mac.

Hope this helps someone else!